# disabling/restricting the LeaveOn date based on JoinOn date using jQuery

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I need to **restrict/disable** the user from selecting a **LeaveOn** date based on the input of his **JoinOn** date. Example: If the user selects **13/10/2018** in the **JoinOn** date, the user should not be able to select the **LeaveOn** date as a date below **13/10/2018** i.e The date cannot be **10/10/2018**.

Following is my code for the same:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#IsPresent').change(function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $('#PresentPanel').hide();
            $('#LeaveOn').val("@(DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"))");
        }
        else {
            $('#PresentPanel').show();
        }
    });
        $('#JoinOn').datetimepicker(
                      {
                          datepicker: true,
                          timepicker: false,
                          format: 'm/d/Y',
                          step: 30,
                          minDate: new Date(1965, 1 - 1, 1),
                          maxDate: new Date()
                      });
        $('#LeaveOn').datetimepicker(
                      {
                          datepicker: true,
                          timepicker: false,
                          format: 'm/d/Y',
                          step: 30,

                          maxDate: new Date()
                      });
    });
```

Comment: so basically you want something which will compare the dates and check if its in past or is it today?

Comment: @UssaidIqbal what I want is that once the user selects the JoinOn date, the LeaveOn date should not be lesser than the JoinOn Date and not more than the Current Date.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume you have datepicker date selected event listener then you can simply add the following code

```js
var LeaveOnSelectedDate = $('#LeaveOn').datepicker('getDate');
var JoinOnDate = $('#JoinOn').datepicker('getDate');
  JoinOnDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  LeaveOnSelectedDate.setHours(0,0,0,0);
  if (LeaveOnSelectedDate <= JoinOnDate) {
    console.log("Date is old or same day!");
  } else {
    console.log("Date is in future!");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(function(e) {
    $('#JoinOn').datetimepicker({
        datepicker: true,
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        maxDate: 0,
        onSelectDate: function(ct, $i) {
            $('#LeaveOn').datetimepicker('setOptions', {
                minDate: ct
            });
        }
    });
    $('#LeaveOn').datetimepicker({
        datepicker: true,
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        maxDate: 0
    });
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/L5dr1yc7/)

Hope this helps